# What's the name of the executable to run GNAT GPS in linux?

Tags: ada, gnat, gnat-gps

IT just installed this on my machine. I'm trying to find the name of the executable to run GNAT GPS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For GNAT GPL on Linux and Mac OS X, there's a script `gps` which sets up environment variables as required by the actual executable `gps_exe`, and then calls it.

For Debian (squeeze, at any rate), there's just `/usr/bin/gnat-gps`.